# UITableView Crashing in iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7, ios8

I Have Created a Table View with Custom cells. I placed that table view on a viewController and i am presenting that viewController whenever Required. it is Working fine in iOS6, iOS7. Coming to iOS8 it is getting crashed and showing an Error Message and in Some times it is getting Crashed Without Showing any Error Message Simply Showing EXC_BADACCESS:

```
-[DropDownViewTableViewCell tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

and Below is the whole console Error Message.

```
2014-11-10 11:09:41.067 BML[1029:26620] -[DropDownViewTableViewCell       tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ccb05e0
2014-11-10 11:09:41.075 BML[1029:26620] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[DropDownViewTableViewCell tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ccb05e0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x0431c946 __exceptionPreprocess + 182
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x03fa1a97 objc_exception_throw + 44
2   CoreFoundation                      0x043245c5 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 277
3   CoreFoundation                      0x0426d3e7 ___forwarding___ + 1047
4   CoreFoundation                      0x0426cfae _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
5   UIKit                               0x02a95449 -[UITableView _delegateWantsHeaderForSection:] + 370
6   UIKit                               0x02c54935 -[UISectionRowData refreshWithSection:tableView:tableViewRowData:] + 169
7   UIKit                               0x02c5b59c -[UITableViewRowData rectForFooterInSection:heightCanBeGuessed:] + 302
8   UIKit                               0x02c5b6c5 -[UITableViewRowData heightForTable] + 68
9   UIKit                               0x02a6c98c -[UITableView _updateContentSize] + 395
10  UIKit                               0x02a8f4a7 -[UITableView didMoveToWindow] + 76
11  UIKit                               0x029fe5b9 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 1703
12  UIKit                               0x02a113e1 -[UIScrollView _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 65
13  UIKit                               0x029fe23f -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 813
14  UIKit                               0x029fe23f -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 813
15  UIKit                               0x029fe23f -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 813
16  UIKit                               0x029fe23f -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 813
17  UIKit                               0x029fe23f -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 813
18  UIKit                               0x029fe23f -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 813
19  UIKit                               0x029f5517 __45-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke + 154
20  UIKit                               0x029f5475 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 458
21  UIKit                               0x02a00f0d -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 2018
22  UIKit                               0x029f386e -[UIView(Hierarchy) addSubview:] + 56
23  UIKit                               0x02aa3b58 -[UITransitionView transition:fromView:toView:removeFromView:] + 1576
24  UIKit                               0x0320826d -[UIViewControllerBuiltinTransitionViewAnimator animateTransition:] + 3551
25  UIKit                               0x02aa91ad __56-[UIPresentationController runTransitionForCurrentState]_block_invoke + 2343
26  UIKit                               0x02adc7ab __40+[UIViewController _scheduleTransition:]_block_invoke + 18
27  UIKit                               0x029a20ce ___afterCACommitHandler_block_invoke + 15
28  UIKit                               0x029a2079 _applyBlockToCFArrayCopiedToStack + 415
29  UIKit                               0x029a1e8e _afterCACommitHandler + 545
30  CoreFoundation                      0x0423f9de __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 30
31  CoreFoundation                      0x0423f920 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 400
32  CoreFoundation                      0x0423535a __CFRunLoopRun + 1226
33  CoreFoundation                      0x04234bcb CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443
34  CoreFoundation                      0x042349fb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
35  GraphicsServices                    0x0684724f GSEventRunModal + 192
36  GraphicsServices                    0x0684708c GSEventRun + 104
37  UIKit                               0x029788b6 UIApplicationMain + 1526
38  BML                                 0x0014bc2d main + 141
39  libdyld.dylib                       0x048b4ac9 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

DropDownViewTableViewCell.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DropDownViewTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageVie;

@end
```

DropDownViewTableViewCell.m

```
#import "DropDownViewTableViewCell.h"

@implementation DropDownViewTableViewCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
 self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
 if (self) {
    // Initialization code
 }
 return self;
}
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    // Initialization code
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

  // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@end
```

TableViewImplementation

```
 - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
   return 35;
 }
 - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
   return 1;
 }
 - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
   return 1;
 }

 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
 // Return the number of rows in the section.
   return [self.poiDataArray count];
 }
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
    DropDownViewTableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell"];
  if (!cell)
  {
       if([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
      {
          [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"DropDownView_iPhone" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"myCell"];
         cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell"];
      }
      else
      {
         [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"DropDownView_iPad" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"myCell"];
         cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell"];
         CGRect frame;

         frame =cell.label.frame;
         frame.size.width +=50;
         cell.label.frame=frame;
      }
  }
  return cell;

 }
```

Comment: Can you please paste the snippet of your `heightForHeaderInSection:` method, including full method name you used?

Comment: `heightForHeaderInSection` is a method defined in `UITableView`. It looks like this is being fired for `UITableViewCell`

Comment: Ah! there you go: `DropDownViewTableViewCell` looks to be a subclass of `UITableViewCell`. `heightForHeaderInSection` responds to `UITableView` and it's subclasses.

Comment: @GoodSp33d Not defined in `UITableView` but in the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol!

Comment: It seems if your setting a cell as delegate for the tableview... Did you set something like  ´[tableView setDelegate:cell]` or similar?

Comment: - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView   heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        return 1;
    }

Comment: @Julian NO i am not Setting any thing but it is working in ios7,6

Comment: and in Some times it is Showing -[_CTNativeGlyphStorage tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: @user3825276 Wow. There must be something **terribly** wrong... I'm sorry, don't think I can help here

Comment: show DropDownViewTableViewCell.h & DropDownViewTableViewCell.m and the implementation of tableView

Comment: @Shoaib please check My Post i have Updated.

Comment: I think it might be helpful to post the code where you are actually instantiating your DropDownViewTableView, especially where you set its delegate.

Comment: i) is this code working in ios7 ii) show where you have set tableView delegate & dataSource.

Comment: i connect DataSource and Delegate using Files Owner.